Ubuntu 22 lagging after installing nvidia 550 driver and I can't revert
I am having a strange issue. I accidentally upgrade to nvidia-driver-550 and I am having serious lagging issues.
It's quite noticeable when using the keyboard or clocking around.
How do I know the lagging is GPU related?

I reverted to nouveau driver and everything works amazing however due to the number of screen I have the CPU just goes nuts so I want to use the GPU.

What have I tried?

I have tried using ubuntu-drivers to install version 525. But it think it's already installed.
I have purged all nvidia using sudo apt-get --purge remove *nvidia*
I have tried installing 525 as follows sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525

However if you study the packages it just reinstall 550 after rebooting you can see it's 550 not 525.

udo apt-get install nvidia-driver-535
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dctrl-tools dkms libnvidia-cfg1-550 libnvidia-common-550 libnvidia-compute-550 libnvidia-decode-550 libnvidia-egl-wayland1 libnvidia-encode-550 libnvidia-extra-550
  libnvidia-fbc1-550 libnvidia-gl-550 nvidia-compute-utils-550 nvidia-dkms-550 nvidia-driver-550 nvidia-firmware-550-550.54.14 nvidia-kernel-common-550 nvidia-kernel-source-550
  nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-550 screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-550
Suggested packages:
  debtags menu
Recommended packages:
  libnvidia-compute-550:i386 libnvidia-decode-550:i386 libnvidia-encode-550:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-550:i386 libnvidia-gl-550:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dctrl-tools dkms libnvidia-cfg1-550 libnvidia-common-550 libnvidia-compute-550 libnvidia-decode-550 libnvidia-egl-wayland1 libnvidia-encode-550 libnvidia-extra-550
  libnvidia-fbc1-550 libnvidia-gl-550 nvidia-compute-utils-550 nvidia-dkms-550 nvidia-driver-535 nvidia-driver-550 nvidia-firmware-550-550.54.14 nvidia-kernel-common-550
  nvidia-kernel-source-550 nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-550 screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-550
0 upgraded, 22 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 10.6 kB/284 MB of archives.
After this operation, 721 MB of additional disk space will be used.


I have tried installing 525-open but I get the error below
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525-open
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nvidia-driver-525-open : Depends: libnvidia-gl-525 (= 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a~dev is to be installed
                        Depends: nvidia-dkms-525-open (<= 525.147.05-1)
                        Depends: nvidia-dkms-525-open (>= 525.147.05)
                        Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-525 (<= 525.147.05-1) but 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a~dev is to be installed
                        Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-525-open (= 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libnvidia-compute-525 (= 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a~dev is to be installed
                        Depends: libnvidia-extra-525 (= 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a~dev is to be installed
                        Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-525 (= 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a~dev is to be installed
                        Depends: libnvidia-decode-525 (= 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a~dev is to be installed
                        Depends: libnvidia-encode-525 (= 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a~dev is to be installed
                        Depends: nvidia-utils-525 (= 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a~dev is to be installed
                        Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-525 (= 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a~dev is to be installed
                        Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-525 (= 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a~dev is to be installed
                        Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-525 (= 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 550.54.14-1pop0~1709151545~22.04~c91e06a~dev is to be installed
                        Recommends: nvidia-prime (>= 0.8)
                        Recommends: libnvidia-compute-525:i386 (= 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but it is not installable
                        Recommends: libnvidia-decode-525:i386 (= 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but it is not installable
                        Recommends: libnvidia-encode-525:i386 (= 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but it is not installable
                        Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-525:i386 (= 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but it is not installable
                        Recommends: libnvidia-gl-525:i386 (= 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


I have tried install nvidia-dkms-525 to try resolve the last issue but no luck.

I am out of ideas and I only solution is to reinstall and setup my dev machine which is a pain in the but to be honest
I am running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Current nvidia driver and card
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.54.14              Driver Version: 550.54.14      CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 ...    Off |   00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   56C    P8             19W /   80W |     428MiB /   8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2300      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            205MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2449      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                           94MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3085      G   ...yOnDemand --variations-seed-version         47MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3266      G   ...seed-version=20240401-050216.270000         35MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5917      G   ...sion,SpareRendererForSitePerProcess         33MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+



Check if the issue is related to input delay on Terminal Ubuntu 22.04.4
If so, you shall fix the lag using mutter provided by this ppa:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vanvugt/mutter
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

